# Превью swf файла

Tags: flash, php

Собственно сабж. Как получить превьюшку swf файла с помощью php и на выходе получить jpg (или png) файл?

Comment: <a href="http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4312-PHP-Render-Flash-canvas-image-as-JPEG.html">Такое</a> не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

1) В PHP для работы с swf-файлами есть функции [Shockwave Flash](http://p-lb.ru/phpf/manphp4rus/f/ref.swf.php.htm) и [Ming](http://p-lb.ru/phpf/manphp4rus/f/ref.ming.php.htm)

2) Можно посмотреть в сторону конвертирования swf2avi и ffmpeg

Comment: То что нужно! Огромное спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 0):

[Export JPEG with Flash/PHP](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/print_screen/)

> В этом уроке мы сосредоточим наше внимание на методе `BitmapData.gePixel()` для того, чтобы трансформировать часть флэш-ролика в формат JPEG (созданный с помощью PHP/GD).

Слова для поиска: swf to jpg php.

Чтобы извлекать картинки из видео, можно также пользоваться [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC5):

```
ffmpeg -i foo.avi -r 1 -s WxH -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg
```

> Это позволит извлечь один кадр в секунду из видео и выведет их в файлы с именами `foo-001.jpeg`, `foo-002.jpeg` и т.д.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста ссылку

Comment: Кхм. А первая строка в ответе это разве не ссылка? :)

Comment: Google > swf to jpg php > первый результат > "How I convert swf to jpg,jpeg using php" > Там его посылают на другой форум или туториал > На форуме его посылают на другой форум > на этом форуме посылают в гугл %)

Есть еще вариант этот http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/print_screen/ но там насколько я понял это делается со стороны ActionScript'a.

Может я ленив, но для того сюда и пришел. Можно пожалуйста ссылку на рабочий результат.